# How to make JPA work on remote server through RMI

Tags: hibernate, jpa, rmi

I am trying to finish a project that sends workload to multiple remote server through RMI. At the end of the work, each remote server will write the result back to a database. I am having some major difficulties to make JPA (HIBERNATE is the provider) work with this solution.

Everything works fine if I can the UpdateDB method to write the data back to database on any of those remote server locally. But it fails to do so if I pass the jar/code/classes through RMI. It raises the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PersistenceUnit
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at cluster.persistence.UpdateDB.execute(UpdateDB.java:148)
at cluster.persistence.UpdateDB.execute(UpdateDB.java:1)
at cms.engine.ComputeEngine.executeTask(ComputeEngine.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.executeTask(Unknown Source)
at cluster.persistence.UpdateDB.main(UpdateDB.java:93)
```

If I try to access the persistence.xml in the code as following:

```
try {
        URL pUrl = UpdateDB.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
        System.out.println(pUrl);

        BufferedReader stream = null;
        InputStream in = UpdateDB.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "META-INF/persistence.xml");
        stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line = null;
        line = stream.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = stream.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The persistenc.xml is accessible through the correct location (jar:htp://MYCODEBASE.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml). And the entire persistence.xml can be printed out correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to make it work so the remote server can write the data back to the database in the RMI set up?

Many thanks.